Handling Long Category Names in Visualizations of Categorical Variables in Python
I'm working with a pandas DataFrame that contains categorical variables, some of which have values with long names. However, some of my categorical features have values with long names, causing the labels to overlap and making the plots difficult to read. I'm attempting to create horizontal bar charts for each categorical variable to visualize their frequencies using the following code:
categorical = [col for col in df.columns if col not in numerical]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 9))
i = 1
for name in categorical:
    ax = fig.add_subplot(3, 6, i)
    i += 1
    df[name].value_counts().plot.barh(ax=ax)
    ax.set_xlabel("Frequency")
    ax.set_ylabel(name)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


What are some strategies I can use to handle long category names and improve the readability of my horizontal bar charts? Are there any adjustments I can make to my code to accommodate long category names more effectively?
Initially, I attempted to arrange the plot using tight layout, but it didn't work as expected. Subsequently, feeling unsure of how to proceed, I sought assistance from a chat, but unfortunately, they were unable to provide a satisfactory solution. After 20 minutes of thinking and researching I still don't have an idea.
